# My referees are in their Ph.D. final year, can they recommend me for Ph.D. Admission?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter, undergraduate

Please I need orientation on this issue. All my undergraduate lecturers that know much about me are in their Ph.D. final year, but they all have been in the system since 16years ago with MSc degree. My MSc supervisor is the only professor that can say much about my research capability. All my undergraduate lecturers are now in their Ph.D. final year. Can I they recommend me for Ph.D. admission? I need three referees, my MSc supervisor and two others would come from my undergraduate degree lecturers. Is this advisable?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When applying for a PhD, is it okay for one letter of recommendation to come from a PhD student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/121340/when-applying-for-a-phd-is-it-okay-for-one-letter-of-recommendation-to-come-fro)

Comment: Also related: [Writing a letter of recommendation as a graduate student](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18062/68109)

Comment: @GoodDeeds I really appreciate your response. The answers in that link give a good insight of what I want, but the difference is that my undergraduate lecturers are yet to accomplish their Ph.D. degree until the later time of this year. Will they be referred to as student or professionals? They have been in the system quite some times now. Is it compulsory my recommenders be Professors or Doctors? This is the bottom-line of my question.